# Initializing localStorage variables with Javascript doesn't work when in a function

Tags: javascript, local-storage

Okay, so I'm using the following if statements to preset certain variables of an application I'm making:

```
if(localStorage.s1 == undefined) {
    localStorage.s1= 50
}
if(localStorage.s2 == undefined) {
    localStorage.s2= 100
}
```

And that works fine. There's about twelve of these presets, so I've re-factored it by using the following function:

```
function setterfunc(targetedelement, presetting) {
    if(localStorage.targetedelement == undefined) {
        localStorage.targetedelement = presetting;
    }
}
```

But when I call it with

```
setterfunc(foobar, 342)
```

Google Chrome console just tells me:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: foobar is not defined
```

Any help? The verbose way around of repeating the if statements works perfectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the bracket notation :

```
function setterfunc(targetedelement, presetting) {
    if(localStorage[targetedelement] == undefined) {
        localStorage[targetedelement] = presetting;
    }
}
setterfunc('foobar', 342)
```

or the `setItem` and `getItem` accessors :

```
function setterfunc(targetedelement, presetting) {
    if(localStorage.getItem(targetedelement) == undefined) {
        localStorage.setItem(targetedelement) = presetting;
    }
}   
setterfunc('foobar', 342)
```

Side note : Be careful that `localStorage` only stores strings. So if you want to handle numbers, you'd better parse what you read from local storage.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Could you clarify what you mean by it only storing strings? The integer 342 appears to be stored by Chrome okay?

Comment: 342 is stored as a string "342". When you read this value later you can convert it back to a number using `Number(x)` `parseInt(x)` or just `x * 1`.

Answer (score 0):

The reason for the error is that the string foobar needs to be quoted, otherwise JS is looking for a variable of this name:

```
slidersetter('foobar', 342);
```

but your function is named `setterfunc`, not `slidersetter`.

Comment: Ah, stupid mistake regarding the function name, thanks for spotting